# Ubuntu 14.04 compiz thumbnails preview flicker

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, compiz

Ubuntu 14.04.1 x64 (upgraded from 12.04) with Unity desktop
Dell Latitude with NVIDIA GF119M (NVS 4200M) - Optimus is DISABLED
Using NVIDIA legacy binary driver 304.117

When I set the CCSM option to allow thumbnail previews, the thumbnail 'flickers' for about 1 second before the actual thumbnail image is displayed.

I don't think I had this enabled under 12.04 so not sure if it's version-specific.

Should I be using a different driver (there are newer ones - Ubu shows NVIDIA binary driver 331.38 and the non-proprietary nouveau, plus NVIDIA has newer ones at the site)?

TIA!